# Magento Paypal payment showing 100 INR as 100 USD

Tags: magento, paypal

I have set base currency as INR but while redirecting on Paypal site it is showing 100 INR as 100 $.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Paypal doesn't support INR,if you want to use paypal as INR you have to modify core files or you can build custom module for the paypal

INR currency convert issue with paypal payment method in magento

Many people facing this issue when customer redirect at paypal payment gateway with INR currency , paypal does not convert Indian currency to USD or any. Here is the little solution that i have mentioned...

Go to app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Block/Standard/Redirect.php

You can see below foreach loop in this file

```
foreach ($standard->getStandardCheckoutFormFields() as $field=>$value) {

  $form->addField($field, 'hidden', array('name'=>$field, 'value'=>$value));

}
```

Just replace above foreach loop with this

```
foreach ($standard->getStandardCheckoutFormFields() as $field=>$value) {
   if($field == 'amount_1'):
    $from = 'INR';
    $to = 'USD';
    $price = $value;
    $newPrice = number_format(Mage::helper('directory')->currencyConvert($price, $from, $to),2);
    $form->addField($field, 'hidden', array('name'=>$field, 'value'=>$newPrice));
   elseif($field == 'amount_2'):
    $from = 'INR';
    $to = 'USD';
    $price = $value;
    $newPrice = number_format(Mage::helper('directory')->currencyConvert($price, $from, $to),2);
    $form->addField($field, 'hidden', array('name'=>$field, 'value'=>$newPrice));
   else:
             $form->addField($field, 'hidden', array('name'=>$field, 'value'=>$value));
   endif;
       }
```

or

you can use below extension

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/paypal-all-currencies.html